# how to force refresh of my screen in JSF

Tags: jsf, icefaces-3

in my JSF2 app I have ​​screens composed with :

- Header
- Body

In the header I have a combo list. At each change in value in the combo list I have an Ajax request that updates the data in the Body. So far everything is working properly. Now the home screen's structure should be change when the value of combo list change. To do this I have :

- 1 ManagedBean HomeBean that manage the home
- 1 ManagedBean HeaderBean that manage the header
- 2 object HomeScreen1.java and HomeScreen2.java that allows me to valued data from each screen
- 2 services HomeScreen1Loader.java and HomeScreen2Loader.java that manage loading of each type of screen
- 1 template home.xhtml
- 2 fichier home1.xhtml et home2.xhtml

When I log in to the application, I get the good page corresponding (Element type 1 => home page 1). But when I select a type 2 item, the actionListener methode is execute, ManagedBean's data was updated (for type 2 screen) , but the page does not updated. What do you do ?

HeaderBean.java :

```
package com.omb.view;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;


import com.omb.exception.TechnicalException;
import com.omb.view.util.Constants;
import com.omb.view.util.FacesUtils;

@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class HeaderBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(HeaderBean.class);
    private List<SelectItem> elementsDisplayed;

    public void initComboList() throws FunctionnalException {
        // init the combo list
    }

    public void elementChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        if (event.getNewValue() != null) {
            // Do traitement....

            ContextBean contextBean = (ContextBean) FacesUtils.getObjectInSession(ContextBean.CONTEXT_BEAN_NAME);
            AbstractBean currentBean = (AbstractBean) FacesUtils.getObjectInSession(contextBean
                    .getCurrentBeanInSession());
            try {
                currentBean.refresh();
            } catch (TechnicalException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    public String disconnect() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }


    public List<SelectItem> getElementsDisplayed() {
        return elementsDisplayed;
    }

    public void setElementsDisplayed(List<SelectItem> elementsDisplayed) {
        this.elementsDisplayed = elementsDisplayed;
    }

}
```

ContextBean.java :

```
package com.omb.view;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.omb.view.util.Constants;

@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class ContextBean {

    public final static String CONTEXT_BEAN_NAME = "contextBean";

    private String templateHomeName;
    private boolean defaultHome;


    public String getTemplateHomeName() {
        return this.templateHomeName;
    }

    public void setTemplateHomeName(String templateHomeName) {
        this.templateHomeName = templateHomeName;
    }

    public boolean isDefaultHome() {
        return this.defaultHome;
    }

    public void setDefaultHome(boolean defaultHome) {
        this.defaultHome = defaultHome;
    }

}
```

HomeBean.java :

```
package com.omb.view.home;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import com.omb.exception.FunctionnalException;
import com.omb.exception.TechnicalException;
import com.omb.view.AbstractBean;
import com.omb.view.util.Constants;


@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class HomeBean extends AbstractBean {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(HomeBean.class);

    public static final String HOME_1_NAME = "home1.xhtml";
    public static final String HOME_2_NAME = "home2.xhtml";

    @Autowired
    private HomeScreen1 homeScreen1;

    @Autowired
    private HomeScreen2 homeScreen2;

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public String display() throws TechnicalException, FunctionnalException {

        ContextBean context = (ContextBean) FacesUtils.getObjectInSession(ContextBean.CONTEXT_BEAN_NAME);

        if (!isInitialized()) {

            if (defaultHomeScreen == null) {
                defaultHomeScreen = new DefaultHomeScreen();
            }

            if (eurHomeScreen == null) {
                eurHomeScreen = new EurHomeScreen();
            }

            AbstractHomeScreenLoader loader = HomeScreenLoaderFactory.getLoader(getTypeElement());
            if (Constants.CODE_TYPE_1.equals(getTypeElement()) {
                loader.load(homeScreen1);
                context.setTemplateHomeName(HOME_1_NAME);
            } else {
                loader.load(homeScreen2);
                context.setTemplateHomeName(HOME_2_NAME);
            }

            setInitialized(true);
        } else if (!upToDate) {
            refresh();
        }

        return "home";

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    public void refresh() throws TechnicalException {
        upToDate = true;
        AbstractHomeScreenLoader loader = HomeScreenLoaderFactory.getLoader(getTypeElement());
        if (Constants.CODE_TYPE_1.equals(userContext.getCurrentHotelCountryId())) {
            loader.refresh(homeScreen1);
        } else {
            loader.refresh(homeScreen2);
        }
    }


    public HomeScreen1 getHomeScreen1() {
        return this.homeScreen1;
    }

    public void setHomeScreen1(HomeScreen1 homeScreen1) {
        this.homeScreen1 = homeScreen1;
    }

    public HomeScreen2 getHomeScreen2() {
        return this.homeScreen2;
    }

    public void setHomeScreen2(HomeScreen2 homeScreen2) {
        this.homeScreen2 = homeScreen2;
    }

}
```

layout.xhtml main template of the application :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">OMB</ui:insert></title>
    <ice:outputStyle href="/xmlhttp/css/xp/xp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/style.css" />

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:panelGroup id="page" styleClass="mainMaster" layout="block">
        <h:panelGroup id="header" styleClass="header" layout="block">
            <ui:insert name="header">
                <ui:include
                    src="/pages/layer/header/#{contextBean.templateHeaderName}" />
            </ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="headerMenu" styleClass="menu" layout="block">
            <ui:insert name="buttons">
                <ui:include
                    src="/pages/layer/menu/#{contextBean.templateMenuButtonName}" />
            </ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="main" styleClass="mainContent" layout="block">
            <h:panelGroup id="content" styleClass="content" layout="block">
                <ui:insert name="content" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="footer" styleClass="footer" layout="block">
            <ui:insert name="footer">
                <ui:include src="/pages/layer/footer/footer.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
</html>
```

header.xhtml, page which manage the combo list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<body>
    <ui:composition>
        <ice:form id="headerForm" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
            xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
            xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

            <h:panelGroup styleClass="logo" layout="block">
                <ice:graphicImage styleClass="imgLogoHR"
                    value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/common/logo/Logo.png" />

                <h:panelGroup styleClass="loginArea" layout="block">
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="area" layout="block">

                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="comboHotel" layout="block">
                            <ace:simpleSelectOneMenu id="selectCurrentElement"
                                value="#{headerBean.currentElementDisplayed}"
                                valueChangeListener="#{headerBean.elementChangeListener}"
                                labelPosition="left" indicatorPosition="left" required="false"
                                rendered="#{not empty headerBean.elementsDisplayed}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{headerBean.elementsDisplayed}" />
                                <ace:ajax execute="@this" render="@all" />
                            </ace:simpleSelectOneMenu>
                        </h:panelGroup>

                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ice:form>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

home.xhtml main template of home page and component should be refresh:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/pages/layer/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <ui:include
                src="/pages/home/#{contextBean.templateHomeName}" />
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the content of the Facelets code where you perform the update and the components that should be updated.

Comment: Hello, I added the layout.xhtml and header.xhtml which contains the combo list. Component which should be refresh it's home.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem came to the ManagedBean ContextBean's templateHomeName attribute  that was not properly valued. I added in loader.load(homeScreen1) and refresh and everything it's ok. I should upgrade my JSF version : 2.1.0-b11 to 2.1.26 because I had an error when refresh.